# How to pump this bicycle tire with this pump?

Tags: pump

How to pump this bicycle tire with this pump?

[image]
[image]
[image]

In general, what are some good material to read to become well knowledgable about bicycle pumps?

Comment: Thats a presta valve and you have a presta->shrader adapter (gray thing). See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncY1PEgSbI0).

Comment: Can you please move this comment to an answer?

Comment: Also, in a pinch, if you don't have an adapter, you can cut the closed tip off of the presta cap, and use that as an adapter. Essentially it just makes the top of the valve body large enough for the pump to seal around. Adapters are better but if you ever find yourself stranded and someone has a Schrader pump you can use this trick!

Also regarding your thirst for knowledge, sheldonbrown.com is your best friend and one of the largest bicycle info databases.

Comment: @qazwsx - A link only answer would be bad; I was hoping someone else would come by and expand it to a proper answer (and someone did). =)

Comment: One problem I have found is that some presta adapters are too short, and some pump chucks will not latch onto them.  It's better to have a pump with an adaptable chuck.

Comment: Can you please explain what is an adaptable chunck ideally with a picture or illustration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment, so I edited Penguino's answer to be completely explicit:

1. Remove valve cap from the step. (Its the (usually) black, plastic piece that completely removes from the valve and serves to protect it from dirt/damage)
2. Unscrew the small knurled knob at the end of the Presta valve (the bit sticking out of the tire) as far as it will go.
3. Press down on the end of the knob a couple of times (momentarily - for less than a second), to loosen the valve in its stem - you should hear air escaping.
4. Screw on the (Presta to Shrader valve) adapter (as you have done in your third photo).
5. If you have a nut on the base of the valve (as shown in the third photo), make sure it is screwed in a decent amount. This will keep the valve from giving way when you are forcing the pump head on.
6. Push the lever on the pump head flush with the body of the pump head (as in your first photo).
7. Push the hole in the pump head firmly down over the adapter and flick the lever out 90 degrees (as shown in your second photo).
8. Pump
9. Flick lever in, remove pump-head, unscrew adaptor, screw in knurled knob. Screw valve cap back on.
10. Ride

Comment: You're right - this should be an edit to the other answer.

Comment: @Criggie I disagree with both of you. If he edited Penguino's answer I would reject as *conflicts with author's intent*. This post was served to me on the low quality queue, and I've said *looks Ok*. David has credited the other answer, so I think it's fine as is. David - check out the privileges in the [help] to see when you get to do what. Cheers

Comment: Throw away the valve cap. ;-) It's merely for decoration purposes and for when new inner tubes are folded up in a box to prevent the end of the valve piercing the new tube. They serve no real purpose, some people think that they keep dirt away but even cyclocrossers don't use them.

Comment: @andy256 What part of the difference between the two answers conflicts with the original author's intent? The changes seem very minor to me and it seems, frankly, ridiculous to assert that the correct procedure is to have two answers which are 90% identical, just because the original author missed one small step.

Comment: I created a new post because I could neither comment nor edit the original post. However, I don't believe the changes are as minor as they may appear to some because things which seem obvious to people with experience may not be so obvious to newbies.

Comment: Also, if someone has the ability to delete my post and edit the changes in to the original, I wouldn't mind in the slightest.

Comment: @DavidR You're welcome to make the edit DavidV suggests. I'll keep out of the approval process; since not everyone agrees with my views the edit may be approved. The site is, after all, mostly moderated by *us*. Maybe your view will prevail :-)

Answer (score 5):

Do it like this:

1. Remove (unscrew) the plastic (?) cap over the Presta valve - if it is there (sometimes it may have already been removed).
2. Unscrew the small knurled knob at the end of the Presta valve (the bit sticking out of the tire) as far as it will go.
3. Press down on the end of the knob a couple of times (momentarily - for less than a second), to loosen the valve in its stem - you should hear air escaping.
4. Screw on the adapter (as you have done in your third photo).
5. Push the lever on the pump head flush with the body of the pump head (as in your first photo).
6. Push the hole in the pump head firmly down over the adapter and flick the lever out 90 degrees (as shown in your second photo).
7. Pump.......
8. Flick lever in, remove pump-head, unscrew adaptor, screw in knurled knob.
9. Ride.......

Comment: Sorry, David - we must have edited at the same time.

Comment: I found that at least for my valve, I needed a critical step 2.5: rotate counter-clockwise a top part (don't know the term) on the valve until it no longer goes. If I didn't do it, like I originally tried to figure it out by just intuition, pumping air will not go into the tire. All the other steps were intuitively clear to me just by laying out all the parts in front of my eyes. See https://www.evernote.com/l/ACEF-YfMG_VPS5mbNOTDtuq14tHB0r6yUQsB/image.png. I insist the answer is incomplete without this step.

Comment: i think that may be what he meant in step 1.

Comment: For my valve, on top of this knurl, there is another cap that needs to be unscrewed and taken off. I mistook that for his step 1.